# Create subreport using Microsoft Reporting from a MySQL database in asp.net 4.0 web forms

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, asp.net-4.0

Create subreport using Microsoft Reporting from a MySQL database in asp.net 4.0 web forms application. Unable to get it working, any good resources to read on the topic?

Found out the problem was with my approach (being first-timer) and as answered below by Kevin, the data source is irrelevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the data is largely irrelevant so you can just use almost any tutorial on sub reports and it will be applicable to MySQL here is one to start http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239314.aspx